# Firefox status bar not showing

Tags: firefox, statusbar

I'm using Firefox 10.0.2 and the Status-4-Evar add-on. The status bar isn't showing, however.

I've recently installed Moonlight, but I've disabled it and still no status.

Now, when hovering over a link, I don't see where it'll lead me.

Any suggestions on how to recover the status bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Control-/` shows and hides the "Add-on bar" at the bottom of your browser.  You can also view and change its status in the View menu.

Comment: Absolutely right. Correct answer. :-)

Comment: It's very easy to disappear it … and some websites like to do that to you in order to hide what they're doing.  I only like to get rid of it when I want more vertical screen real estate.